# Remove selected destination from dropdown list to another dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am currently developing an airline reservation using PHP(Codeigniter). Currently the fields/radio buttons that I have:

**2 radio button**

1) One way

2) Round Trip

**2 dropdown list**

1) From

2) To

and so on..

When the user trying to book, the user can't repeat the destination he inputted  "from destination" into "to destination". Example: I have 3 destinations; 1) Country 1; 2) Country 2; 3) Country 3, then user tries to book. From: Country 1, To: Country1. The Country 1 in the "To:"  should not be display because he already use it in the From Destination.

NOTE: The thing that I do first is, call all the available destinations in my controller then call it in my view using my foreach.

```
<div class="pure-u-1-1 fromto">
               <div class="pure-u-1-1">
                  <label for="from" class="margin2px">From</label>
                  <!-- <input type="text" class="fromto"><br> -->
                  <select class="fromto" name="flight_from">
                  <?php foreach($flight as $a):?>
                    <option value ="<?= $a->flight_name?>" ><?= $a->flight_destination?></option>
                  <?php endforeach?>

                  </select>

               </div>
                <div class="pure-u-1-1">
                  <label for="to" class="tomargin">To</label>
                  <!-- <input type="text" class="fromto"><br> -->
                  <select class="fromto" name="flight_to">
                    <?php foreach($flight as $a):?>
                      <option value ="<?= $a->flight_name?>" ><?= $a->flight_destination?></option>
                    <?php endforeach?>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

Question: How can I prevent it from repeating the country I selected in my "from destination" into "to destination"?

Comment: may you use a client side scripting language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use jQuery:

```js
$('select[name=flight_from]').on('change',function(){
  $("select[name=flight_to]").find('option').show();
  var from = $(this).find(":selected").val();
  $("select[name=flight_to]").val('');
  if ( from != "" ) {
      $("select[name=flight_to]").find( 'option:contains("'+from+'")' ).hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<select name="flight_from">
  <option value="">-- Please select depature --</option>
  <option>Country 1</option>
  <option>Country 2</option>
  <option>Country 3</option>
</select>

<select name="flight_to">
  <option value="">-- Please select destination --</option>
  <option>Country 1</option>
  <option>Country 2</option>
  <option>Country 3</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried to do some research regarding this, but what I saw is how to remove duplicate entry in the dropdown list.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that ;)